# swiftUI hover for IOS

Tags: swift, swiftui

I trying to make hover effect like swiftUI Menu (the background color changes when the buttons are swiped, example: [veed.io/view/85e8df0d-14b6-44d1-a88e-31ac663246d1](https://veed.io/view/85e8df0d-14b6-44d1-a88e-31ac663246d1))

```
Menu("Image Editing") {
    Button {} label: {
        Label("Markup", systemImage: "pencil.tip.crop.circle")
    }
    Button {} label: {
        Label("Crop", systemImage: "selection.pin.in.out")
    }
    Button {} label: {
        Label("Compress", systemImage: "rectangle.compress.vertical")
    }
}
```

For macOS i used a hover proprieties

```
struct MenuButtonView: View {
    @State private var isHovered = false
    
    var item: UIMenuElement
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("\(item.title) tapped")
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(item.title)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(MenuButtonStyle(isHovered: $isHovered))
        .onHover { hovering in
            isHovered = hovering
        }
        .frame(height: 20)
    }
}

struct MenuButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Binding var isHovered: Bool
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(
                        configuration.isPressed
                        ? Color.gray.opacity(0.15)
                        : isHovered ? Color.gray.opacity(0.15) : Color.clear
                    )
                    .frame(height: 40)
            )
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1.0)
    }
}
```

its works fine, but for iOS i cant get this effect, i tried something like this

```
    .gesture(
        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0)
            .updating($isLongPressed) { value, state, _ in
                state = value
                isHovered = value
            }
    )
or 
DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
    .updating($isHovered) { value, state, _ in
        state = value.startLocation == value.location
        isHovered = value.startLocation == value.location
}
```

But there's no effect. Could you please tell me how to make this effect? Or maybe there is a possibility to show `Menu` programmatically?

Comment: AFAIK onHover only works when you have a "pointer", e.g. mouse. Did you test it with mouse / some other pointer device plugged?

Comment: @timbretimbre onHover  works fine for macOS, but i need also add support for iOS. I know that hover its not support for iOS, but we can do the same, can't we? for example Menu in swiftUI. The problem is that idk how, i tried with LongPressGesture and DragGesture but there's no effect

Comment: There is no such  thing as hovering in iOS. You have to rethink what you are trying to do. For example highlighting something that is at the center of the screen or using tap and double tap, etc.

Comment: @loremipsum i am try to make something like https://veed.io/view/85e8df0d-14b6-44d1-a88e-31ac663246d1 its a highlighting a button when is on focus. For mac is i using "onHover" and update the background - its working fine, but for iOS i dont know what to use to make that effect. Can you help me please ?

Comment: That doesn’t exist in iOS. There is no way to duplicate it because there is no such action.

Comment: @loremipsum but many apps was make it like "telegram" or "whatsup". There is no way to show this menu programmatically then i think they do own realization of this menu. Or i am wrong ?

Comment: I don’t use either. But I can almost guarantee that they don’t use SwiftUI. SwiftUI is very new and very limiting it is not used by the most custom apps. Like I said in my first comment you just have to reimagine the UI, hovering isn’t a thing in iOS, dragging, tapping, UI position, etc. SwiftUI is like using training wheels.